# Adding writer function to tunnel program

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, rust, tunnel

How do I create a writer function for the tunnel program below? The code below is a sample program to create windows tunnel interface. I want to write a function that writes (or sends) packets to another server IP address. Github link for full code and its dependencies given below.

https://github.com/nulldotblack/wintun/blob/main/examples/basic.rs

```
use log::*;
use std::sync::{
atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering},
Arc,
};

static RUNNING: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(true);
fn main() {
env_logger::init();
let wintun = unsafe { wintun::load_from_path("examples/wintun/bin/amd64/wintun.dll") }
    .expect("Failed to load wintun dll");
let version = wintun::get_running_driver_version(&wintun);
info!("Using wintun version: {:?}", version);

let adapter = match wintun::Adapter::open(&wintun, "Demo") {
    Ok(a) => a,
    Err(_) => wintun::Adapter::create(&wintun, "Example", "Demo", None)
        .expect("Failed to create wintun adapter!"),
};

let version = wintun::get_running_driver_version(&wintun).unwrap();
info!("Using wintun version: {:?}", version);

let session = Arc::new(adapter.start_session(wintun::MAX_RING_CAPACITY).unwrap());

let reader_session = session.clone();
let reader = std::thread::spawn(move || {
    while RUNNING.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
        match reader_session.receive_blocking() {
            Ok(packet) => {
                let bytes = packet.bytes();
                println!(
                    "Read packet size {} bytes. Header data: {:?}",
                    bytes.len(),
                    &bytes[0..(20.min(bytes.len()))]
                );
            }
            Err(_) => println!("Got error while reading packet"),
        }
    }
});
println!("Press enter to stop session");

let mut line = String::new();
let _ = std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut line);
println!("Shutting down session");

RUNNING.store(false, Ordering::Relaxed);
session.shutdown();
let _ = reader.join();

println!("Shutdown complete");
```

}

Comment: Isn't [readme example](https://github.com/nulldotblack/wintun#example) doing the same thing?

Comment: There is a writer function in the wireshark.rs file in that github link under examples folder. So in that file's program they have created a thread for writer function to send random icmp packets to a server. How should the writer code be modified to function in the code example i have given above in the question?

Comment: so you want to intercept the incoming/outgoing packets on the system and want to send those packets to some other server??

Comment: I'm not expert in these fields, but i don't think it'd work. if the connection is https, those packets will contain the encrypted data, so you can't make sense out of those. can you please describe what are you trying to build on a higher level?

Comment: I'm building a Windows UDP tunnel client that can receive packets from the UDP server on another external system. The client receives random packets from the system and also packets from the server using one threader called reader. The other thread called writer, will send random packets generated by client system to the server system.

Comment: seems interesting stuff.. :) but i'm not yet that pro.. there are many pro people [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/), you can ask your question there, they may help you.